# Problema com ngFor

Tags: angular

Atualizei meu projeto para angular 9 e minhas páginas com `ngFor` e `ngIf` pararam de funcionar, aparece:

> core.js:12768 Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Como erro no navegador, em qualquer tag que eu use aparece o mesmo erro. Já adicionei o `CommonModule` tanto no `app.module` quanto na `adddate.module` e segue sem funcionar. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ModalModule, BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AgendamentosComponent } from './agendamentos/agendamentos.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AlertModalComponent } from './alert-modal/alert-modal.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { AddDateComponent } from './add-date/add-date.component';
import { AddAgComponent } from './add-ag/add-ag.component';
import { SalasComponent } from './salas/salas.component';
import { Agendamentos12Component } from './agendamentos12/agendamentos12.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AgendamentosNoiteComponent } from './agendamentos-noite/agendamentos-noite.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AgendamentosComponent,
    LoginComponent,
AddDateComponent,
    AlertModalComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AddAgComponent,
    SalasComponent,
    Agendamentos12Component,
    HeaderComponent,
    AgendamentosNoiteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],


  providers:[BsModalRef, BsModalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Se este for o módulo raiz do projeto (`AppModule`), você deve manter apenas o `BrowserModule` no `imports: []` do `@NgModule()`.

Se não for o módulo raiz do projeto, você mantém apenas o `CommonModule`:

```
// Antes era da seguinte forma:
// import {BrowserModule, CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

// Agora é assim:
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
..
..
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, /* ou CommonModule */],
  ..
})
```